# JavaScript Fade In/Out issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some difficulty trying to get my Fade In and out effect working properly. I think I am over complicating it.

I have 4 images, however only the first 2 need to be faded out and in on hover of the image (The other 2 images come into play with some other feature on the page).

My HTML is:

```
<div class="square">
    <div class="imageHolder">    
        <!--Comment out and uncomment BG image to show transitions on BG images-->    
        <img class="one" src="image_01.jpg" />
        <img class="two" src="image_02.jpg" />
        <img class="three" src="image_03.jpg" />
        <img class="four" src="image_04.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Images, two, three, four are displayed none

JS:

```
$('.square').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).find('img').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('class') === 'two') {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                }
                if ($(this).attr('class') === 'one') {
                    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                }
            });
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks for the responses.

I was trying to be too clever and it didn't need it. Is there a way for the the fadein and out to happen simultaneously without the use for a plugin?

Comment: You really should use hasClass() if you are going to see if it has a class.

Comment: In the code posted in answers if should happen simultaneously. What do you mean by *without the use for a plugin*? Without using jQuery? If so, is there any reason you don't want to use it? Well, it's possible to do it, but it would require some more code and then you should make sure it works correctly on different browsers because of browsers' differences.

Comment: With jQuery but without an additional plugin, at the minute it fades the default image out and then fades the new image in. Ideally it needs to happen at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this:

```
$(".one").fadeIn("slow", function() { $(this).fadeOut("slow") });
$(".two").fadeIn("slow", function() { $(this).fadeOut("slow") });
```

Update:

I misread you question and thought you want both to fade in and out. To make the first one fade in and the second fade out use something like this:

```
$(".one").fadeIn("slow");
$(".two").fadeOut("slow");
```

If you have other elements with `one` and `two` classes and don't want to affect them, you can type `$(".imageHolder .one")` and `$(".imageHolder .two")` instead of `$(".one")` and `$(".two")`.

If you have multiple `imageHolder` elements on your page, use `find()` function as suggested by *epascarello* or *sushanth reddy*.

Answer (score 1):

Why do the each and not just selected them?

```
var imgs = $(this).find("img");
imgs.filter(".one").fadeOut('slow');
imgs.filter(".two").fadeIn('slow');
```

or

```
var imgs = $(this);
imgs.find(".one").fadeOut('slow');
imgs.find(".two").fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way for the the fadein and out to happen simultaneously without the use for a plugin other than jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a .each loop .. Just find the img inside the div and do your operations on it

Try this instead..

```
$('.square').mouseover(function() {

    $(this).find('.two').fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).find('.one').fadeOut('slow');

});​
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/u6dpt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
  $('.square img')
    .mouseover(function () {
      $(this).fadeIn('slow');
    })
    .mouseout(function () {
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will better use jquery.hoverIntent.js. It will create a little delay time when you will move your cursor rapidly over  the different images.

an example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var config = {    
     interval: 230,
     over: zoomIn,
     out: zoomOut  
    };

    $("div#clients_wrap div").hoverIntent(config);

    });
```

zoomIn en zoomOut are functions, you could declare them with an fadein, fadeout respectively. This is just an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Basically assign a class to the group of images that need to fade in/out on hover in/out respectively

```
<div class="square">
        <div class="imageHolder">    
            <!--Comment out and uncomment BG image to show transitions on BG images-->    
            <img class="one fadeeffect" src="image_01.jpg" />
            <img class="two fadeeffect" src="image_02.jpg" />
            <img class="three" src="image_03.jpg" />
            <img class="four" src="image_04.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.fadeeffect')..hover(function(){
    // write your code here
}
```